# Viewing database in Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So this morning I woke up to a minor Firebase Console design. The left side menu usually has
Authentication
Database
Functions
I don't remember the fourth item

But today there is Realtime Database and a couple of added items [see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQrb0.png). When I click Realtime Database I can not see my existing database but instead see a CTA to create a database and some documentation links.

I am using the following link to access the console https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/my-project-name

How can I can access my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tag used in your question I understand that you are using Cloud Firestore (and not the Realtime Database).

Firebase offers two cloud-based database services, which both support realtime data syncing: [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) and the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) (the Firebase's original database)

Before yesterday (12 August 2020), on the Firebase console, there was only one vertical menu item for these two database Services.

Yesterday, this unique vertical menu item for Database Services was splitted in two: one vertical menu item for Firestore and one for the Realtime Database.

The URLs for each database "console page" have therefore changed. To access your Firestore database console you should select the "Cloud Firestore" vertical menu item.